# AngularJS push to array retrieved by $resource query and save

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Checkout the code below.  The question is in the comments.

```
angular.module('MainStreetMower.services', ['ngResource'])
.factory('Videos', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/jobs/1/');
});
function VideoListCtrl($scope, Videos) {
    $scope.videos = Videos.query();
    $scope.what = function() {
        // proper way to push to the videos array and $save() the new array.
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to describe what you want more clearly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would say the following:

```
function VideoListCtrl($scope, Videos) {
    $scope.videos = Videos.query();

    $scope.what = function() {

        var newVideoData = {}; // prepare new video data here from the model
        new Videos(newVideoData).$save(function(video){
          $scope.videos.push(video);
        }); 

    }
}
```

if you don't want to refresh the whole list. Alternatively you could re-query the collection in the save callback is you expect changes from other sources:

```
new Videos(newVideoData).$save(function(video){
   $scope.videos = Videos.query();
});
```

Please note that you could use the `save` method on the class level. For example, the code above could re-written as:

```
Videos.save(newVideoData, function(video){
   $scope.videos = Videos.query();
});
```

Comment: Oh, duh.  I need new Videos().  I should have asked how do I access $scope.videos to $save() an updated video. But, that totally changes the question...

Comment: Now you got me confused :-) What is the real question then? Do my explanations help you or not?

Comment: I'll ask a new related question eventually.  Your answer solves the problem stated so it's answered.